# sql подстановка значений из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть 2 таблицы: 
Колеса(Ид, Имя колеса),
Машины(Ид, Имя машины, Ид левого колеса, Ид правого колеса)

Между ними две связи по ключам:
Car.id_left_wheel ==> wheel.id_wheel
Car.id_right_wheel ==> wheel.id_wheel

[image: Таблицы]
.

Я написал следующие запросы:

```
SELECT Car.id AS [Ид], Car.name AS [Имя машины], wheel.name AS [Имя левого колеса] FROM Car
INNER JOIN wheel
    ON Car.id_left_wheel = wheel.id_wheel;

SELECT Car.id AS [Ид], Car.name AS [Имя машины], wheel.name AS [Имя правого колеса] FROM Car
INNER JOIN wheel
    ON Car.id_right_wheel = wheel.id_wheel;

SELECT Car.id AS [Ид], Car.name AS [Имя машины], wheel.name AS [Имя левого колеса], wheel.name AS [Имя правого колеса] FROM Car
INNER JOIN wheel
    ON Car.id_left_wheel = wheel.id_wheel
    AND Car.id_right_wheel = wheel.id_wheel;
```

Логично, что первый запрос возвращает :

[image: Первый запрос]

А второй запрос возвращает:

[image: Второй запрос]

То третий не возвращает ничего:

[image: Третий запрос]

Отсюда вопрос, как мне изменить запрос или что использовать вместо INNER JOIN, что бы вместо id_left_wheel и id_right_wheel в таблице Car подставлялись значения name из таблицы wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Car.id AS [Ид], 
       Car.name AS [Имя машины], 
       wheel1.name AS [Имя левого колеса], 
       wheel2.name AS [Имя правого колеса] 
FROM Car
INNER JOIN wheel wheel1
    ON Car.id_left_wheel = wheel1.id_wheel
INNER JOIN wheel wheel2
    ON Car.id_right_wheel = wheel2.id_wheel;
```

Comment: Т.е. при записи wheel1.name, он создает какие то временные копии таблиц?

Comment: Нет. Это просто две независимые копии одной таблицы. Скажем, это два разных глаза, глядящие в одну и ту же таблицу, но каждый со своей стороны. Никакие копии не создаются.

Comment: понял, спасибо большое!